# нужно чтобы 3 префаба спавнились рандомно в заданных мной векторах

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public GameObject[] prefs;
public Vector3[] poSrnd;

void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine(timer());
}


IEnumerator timer()
{

    Random Prnd = new Random();
    Random Prefrnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100500; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Instantiate(prefs[Prefrnd.Next(0,3)],poSrnd[Prnd.Next(3)],Quaternion.identity);
    }//тут первый префаб спавнится в первом заданом векторе
     //второй во втором а я хочу чтобы они чередовались в рандомном порядке

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удобства в Unity имеется собственный генератор псевдослучайных чисел в пространстве имен `UnityEngine`.

Попробуйте так:

```
Instantiate(prefs[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,3)], poSrnd[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,3)], Quaternion.identity);
```